# Converting datetime64 to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

How can I convert timestamp column of dataframe to numeric value? The datatype of the below Time column in below dataframe 'df' is 'datetime64'.

```
       Time          Count
2018-05-15 00:00:00    4
2018-05-15 00:15:00    1
2018-05-15 00:30:00    5
2018-05-15 00:45:00    6
2018-05-15 01:15:00    3
2018-05-15 01:30:00    4
2018-05-15 02:30:00    5
2018-05-15 02:45:00    3
2018-05-15 03:15:00    2
2018-05-15 03:30:00    5
```

Comment: What kind of number do you want to represent those timestamps? Number of seconds since some date? Number of minutes since midnight?

Comment: If it's not obvious why the comment by @ALollz makes your question impossible to answer as written, consider that `df.Time = 42` converts the column to a numeric value, which is all you've specified, but is almost certainly useless.

Answer (score 1):

By using `to_numeric`

```
pd.to_numeric(df.Time)
Out[218]: 
0    1526342400000000000
1    1526343300000000000
2    1526344200000000000
3    1526345100000000000
4    1526346900000000000
5    1526347800000000000
6    1526351400000000000
7    1526352300000000000
8    1526354100000000000
9    1526355000000000000
Name: Time, dtype: int64
```

Comment: These values get changed when I export dataframe to csv. I have same values for most columns. They are not unique